# Level Editor for iOS Games

Tags: game-design, ios, iphone, level-design, xcode

What would be the best way to design "Angry Birds" - levels. I wanna develop my own Angry Birds but I don't know how I should design the levels. Is there any good tool/level editor for that?[image]

The app is going to be an iPhone app and I use SpriteKit.

Answer (score 1):

Build your own level editor - it's the conclusion I came to after having developed several games.
A simple editor would involve creating some simple buttons (the items in the levels) and some simple logic for positioning, rotating and scaling them on stage.
After you have all the items in a level just push their details (position, type, etc) to an/or several arrays and encode these to string.

All you have to do in your game is decode the level strings and loop through your data and place the items in the level that has just started.

Good luck with your game.

Comment: This is the conclusion I came to after a few games as well. It's actually not as difficult as you would think to build your own editor, and it gives you significant experience that would benefit you.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I think that would be a good way to do it.. Do you know if I could also use TiledMap for this?

Comment: You can use Tiled Map ... it's the same principle: make some tiles, position them on screen (make them snap to location multiple of tile width/height) and then just loop through all of them and add them to your tile array/matrix; then encode that array and use it in your game.